# Embedded xml database with .NET binding

Tags: .net, windows-ce, xml-database

Does anybody know an embedded ***XML*** database which can run on Windows Ce 6.0 and which has .NET bindings

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention it ought to be XML database

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like: ["SQL Server CE 2.0 and the .NET Compact Framework"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188785.aspx)

If this is what you seek,I am sure a quick search in the spirit of the above mentioned will result similar things with later versions (like SqlCE 3.5).

Answer (score 0):

The default database for Windows CE is CEDB. Windows CE also includes support for the embedded database (EDB), which enhances the functionality of CEDB . 
These are ancient databases which are mostly used in SDK, MFC windows CE application.

Information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885343.aspx

If you want to build an application in .Net you can simply use SQL Server CE database version supported to .Net framework (as suggested by "Shaihi"), which is wrapper over EDB(Embedded database).

I think for cross platform application, SQLITE is best option.

Also please check satckoverflow's link similar to your post:
[Embedded Database for .net that can run off a network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705/embedded-database-for-net-that-can-run-off-a-network)

Comment: No, that's not what I need. I need an XML native database, i.e. database which can store XML documents and do manipulations on the using XPath/XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd add an answer in case anyone stumbles on it. My company just released an open source embedded XML database for the .NET platform called Nxdb. It's under the Apache 2.0 license and has been in development and use internally for several years. It's basically a binding to a cross-compiled (using IKVM) version of BaseX (a fantastic Java XML database) along with extra functionality for the embedded use case and the .NET environment. The project page is here: https://dracorp.assembla.com/spaces/nxdb

(Hopefully linking to my own project doesn't irk the mods, but I figured since this post directly answers the question and provides a link to a permissive OS project it would be okay).

Comment: It is ok to promote your own project in SO (even comercial ones) as long as it solves the problem presented by the OP. The only problem I see in this case is that your project is based on the **full** .Net framework, and this question is about Windows CE, which only supports .Net compact framework. I think it is unlikely that your project can be used in this scenario.

Comment: You are correct about not working on Windows CE - I wasn't thinking and missed the connection there between CE and .NET CF. Though the Nxdb code itself would probably run (or could be made to run) under the compact framework, it relies heavily on IKVM which is not currently compatible with .NET CF.